# How to handle both success and fail responses in Retrofit and RxJava2?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have the following request:

```
@POST("devices/link/")
    fun linkDevice(
        @Body deviceInfo: DeviceInfo
    ): Single<Response<UserDevice>>
```

I want to achieve the following:

1. If request was successful, get DeviceInfo and, depending on status code, report event to analytics
2. If request failed, get exception, transform it and rethrow.

So, the code is:

```
fun linkDevice(): Single<UserDevice> {
    val deviceInfo = deviceUtil.getDeviceInfo()

    return devicesService
        .linkDevice(deviceInfo)
        .onErrorResumeNext { e ->
            val transformedException = transformRequestException(e) { httpException ->
                return@transformRequestException when (httpException.code()) {
                    409 -> DeviceAlreadyLinkedException()
                    else -> null
                }
            }
            Single.error(transformedException)
        }
        .flatMap { response ->
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val userDevice = response.body()

                userDevice?.let {
                    userPreferences.setDeviceId(it.id)
                }

                when (response.code()) {
                    200 -> {
                        // TODO: Analytics
                    }
                    201 -> {
                        // TODO: Analytics
                    }
                }

                Single.just(userDevice)
            } else {
                throw ApiException()
            }
        }
}

/**
 * Transform exception that came from request
 * By default, handles only network and HTTP 401 exceptions, but can contain custom logic, passed with specialTransformer
 */
fun transformRequestException(
    e: Throwable,
    specialTransformer: ((httpException: HttpException) -> Exception?)? = null
): Exception {
    return if (e is HttpException) {
        if (e.code() == 401) {
            NotAuthenticatedException()
        } else {
            specialTransformer?.invoke(e) ?: ApiException()
        }
    } else {
        NetworkException()
    }
}
```

But this code does not work, if I operate with Response object, it will work only with `Single<UserDevice>` in my Retrofit service.

But, with `Single<UserDevice>` I can't get 2XX codes.

So, how to implement the desired behavior?

Comment: do you need to differentiate between 200 and 201 ?

Comment: @Blackbelt 200 indicates that existing device is re-linked and 201 that new device is linked. I need to pass that to analytics.

Comment: How about `Single<Result<UserDevice>>`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce `Result` indicates error == false even on error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as for now, I've solved as following:

```
data class RequestResult<T>(
    val data: T,
    val code: Int
)

fun <T> transformResponse(response: Response<T>): Single<RequestResult<T>> {
    if (response.isSuccessful) {
        return Single.just(RequestResult(response.body()!!, response.code()))
    } else {
        throw HttpException(response)
    }
}

fun <T> transformEmptyResponse(response: Response<T>): Completable {
    if (response.isSuccessful) {
        return Completable.complete()
    } else {
        throw HttpException(response)
    }
}
```

And:

```
fun linkDevice(): Single<UserDevice> {
    val deviceInfo = deviceUtil.getDeviceInfo()

    return devicesService
        .linkDevice(deviceInfo)
        .flatMap { transformResponse(it) }
        .flatMap { requestResult ->
            requestResult.data.let { userDevice ->
                userPreferences.setDeviceId(userDevice.id)
                when (requestResult.code) {
                    200 -> {
                        // TODO: Analytics
                    }
                    201 -> {
                        // TODO: Analytics
                    }
                }

                Single.just(userDevice)
            }
        }
        .onErrorResumeNext { e ->
            val transformedException = transformRequestException(e) { httpException ->
                return@transformRequestException when (httpException.code()) {
                    409 -> DeviceAlreadyLinkedException()
                    else -> null
                }
            }
            Single.error(transformedException)
        }
}
```

Looks like hack, but I did not find any better solution, and it works.